# Return Matched Value to Dataframe from Uneven List

Tags: r, list, match

I've looked at several SO posts but I'm at the "beating head against tree" stage. I appreciate your time.

I have a dataframe (about 300 cases) with a text string; I simply want to scan a separate list of cities (7000 of them), and if city in the string matches the list, I want a new data frame column to be written with the matching city name.

My data:

```
df<-structure(list(Item = c("1965 Wilkes College, Wilkes-Barre, PA", "1967 Spanish National Tourist Office, New York City", "1968 William Penn Memorial Museum, Harrisburg, PA", 
"2010 Strange Evidence. Philadelphia Museum of Art. Peter Barbarie, Curator.","1973 The Museum of Modern Art, New York City", "1974 International Museum of Photography, George Eastman House, Rochester, NY",  "1974 Light Gallery, New York City", "1975 Art Institute of Chicago"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))

citylist<-c("Barre","Sacramento","Palmer", "New York City","Chicago","Rochester")
```

I've tried things like:

```
 df$city<-sapply(df$Item,function(x) df$Item[df$Item %in% citylist])
```

Or

```
citymatcher<-function(x){match(x,citylist)} 
df$city<-sapply(df$Item,citymatcher)
```

Ultimately, I want a tidy dataframe with a new column indicating the city that matches a given row.

Comment: if it is a partial match, you may need regex `df %>% mutate(city = str_extract(Item, str_c(citylist, collapse = "|")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `str_match`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

pattern <- paste(citylist, collapse = '|')

mutate(df, city = str_match(Item, pattern))
```

```
 Item                                                                          city_1[,1]   
  <chr>                                                                         <chr>        
1 1965 Wilkes College, Wilkes-Barre, PA                                         Barre        
2 1967 Spanish National Tourist Office, New York City                           New York City
3 1968 William Penn Memorial Museum, Harrisburg, PA                             NA           
4 1973 The Museum of Modern Art, New York City                                  New York City
5 1974 International Museum of Photography, George Eastman House, Rochester, NY Rochester    
6 1974 Light Gallery, New York City                                             New York City
7 1975 Art Institute of Chicago                                                 Chicago      
>
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `regex_left_join` (from `fuzzyjoin`) after creating a `data.frame/tibble` from the 'citylist' vector

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(df, tibble(city = citylist), by = c("Item" = "city"))
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  Item                                                                          city         
  <chr>                                                                         <chr>        
1 1965 Wilkes College, Wilkes-Barre, PA                                         Barre        
2 1967 Spanish National Tourist Office, New York City                           New York City
3 1968 William Penn Memorial Museum, Harrisburg, PA                             <NA>         
4 1973 The Museum of Modern Art, New York City                                  New York City
5 1974 International Museum of Photography, George Eastman House, Rochester, NY Rochester    
6 1974 Light Gallery, New York City                                             New York City
7 1975 Art Institute of Chicago                                                 Chicago
```

---

Just to avoid any partial substring match, use word boundary (`\\b`)

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr) 
regex_left_join(df, tibble(city = sprintf("\\b%s\\b", 
       citylist)), by = c("Item" = "city")) %>%
    mutate(city = str_remove_all(city, fixed("\\b")))
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Item                                                                          city         
  <chr>                                                                         <chr>        
1 1965 Wilkes College, Wilkes-Barre, PA                                         Barre        
2 1967 Spanish National Tourist Office, New York City                           New York City
3 1968 William Penn Memorial Museum, Harrisburg, PA                             <NA>         
4 2010 Strange Evidence. Philadelphia Museum of Art. Peter Barbarie, Curator.   <NA>         
5 1973 The Museum of Modern Art, New York City                                  New York City
6 1974 International Museum of Photography, George Eastman House, Rochester, NY Rochester    
7 1974 Light Gallery, New York City                                             New York City
8 1975 Art Institute of Chicago                                                 Chicago
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  To improve the matching, I will remove works like "museum" that sometimes match with my city list.   If I wanted only an **exact** match, what approach would you recommend?

Comment: @Ben `str_extract` as in my comments should also work, but if you have a vector of length 7000, it may not work as there is a limit for `|`.  Regarding your comment, can you update your post with an example where this occurs so that I can test it

Comment: @Ben I tried your new data, but I don't see any issue with the matching i.e. we get two `NA` for the rows `1968 William Penn Memorial Museum, Harrisburg, PA` and `Strange Evidence. Philadelphia Museum of Art. Peter Barbarie, Curator.` these ones doesn't have the corresponding `citylist` values

Comment: @Ben Are you concerned about `Art Institute of Chicago` where `Chicago` matches? which seems difficult to matches unless you have some pattern to show how the city names should be matched

Comment: I added another row of data ("2010 Strange...") which returns the value "Muse" in the city column.  Not sure why that match occurs, as I searched in my whole citylist for "Muse" and "muse" and nothing matches.  See https://github.com/bac3917/Cauldron/blob/master/citylist.csv

Comment: @Ben For me the output from that row is `NA` `4 2010 Strange Evidence. Philadelphia Museum of Art. Peter Barbarie, Curator.   <NA>`

Comment: @Ben Can you try `regex_left_join(df, tibble(city = sprintf("\\b%s\\b", citylist)), by = c("Item" = "city")) %>%mutate(city = str_remove_all(city, fixed("\\b")))`

Comment: I get  rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` column `city`.
i `city = str_remove_all(city, fixed("\\b"))`.
x no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('criterion', 'function')"
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
 10. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 11. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))

Comment: @Ben that seems like a different error, probably some version issues.  Can you check the output of `regex_left_join(df, tibble(city = sprintf("\\b%s\\b", 
       citylist)), by = c("Item" = "city"))`

Comment: unfortunately not.  The method you recommend also creates additional records.  See my comment in the Answer below. I do appreciate the use of fuzzyjoin, so thanks for sharing that idea!

Comment: @Ben that could be because of duplicate elements in citylist.  Can you check for duplicates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242337/discussion-between-ben-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

# collapse citylist into a regex search string
city_regex <- str_c(citylist, collapse = "|")

# extract matching values using stringr::str_extract
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(city = str_extract(Item, city_regex))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Item                                                                          city         
  <chr>                                                                         <chr>        
1 1965 Wilkes College, Wilkes-Barre, PA                                         Barre        
2 1967 Spanish National Tourist Office, New York City                           New York City
3 1968 William Penn Memorial Museum, Harrisburg, PA                             NA           
4 1973 The Museum of Modern Art, New York City                                  New York City
5 1974 International Museum of Photography, George Eastman House, Rochester, NY Rochester    
6 1974 Light Gallery, New York City                                             New York City
7 1975 Art Institute of Chicago                                                 Chicago
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible base R solution:

```
citylist2 <- paste0(citylist, collapse = "|")

df$city <- ifelse(grepl(citylist2, df$Item), sub(paste0(".*(", citylist2, ").*"), "\\1", df$Item), NA)
```

Or we could use `regexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
citylist2 <- paste0(citylist, collapse = "|")

df$city <- NA
df[grepl(citylist2, df$Item),]$city <- regmatches(df$Item, regexpr(citylist2, df$Item))
```

**Output**

```
  Item                                                                          city         
  <chr>                                                                         <chr>        
1 1965 Wilkes College, Wilkes-Barre, PA                                         Barre        
2 1967 Spanish National Tourist Office, New York City                           New York City
3 1968 William Penn Memorial Museum, Harrisburg, PA                             NA           
4 1973 The Museum of Modern Art, New York City                                  New York City
5 1974 International Museum of Photography, George Eastman House, Rochester, NY Rochester    
6 1974 Light Gallery, New York City                                             New York City
7 1975 Art Institute of Chicago                                                 Chicago
```

**Benchmark**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrews, but I get an regex memory error, even after cleaning up the cache and rebooting R.